# MySQL data not updating

Tags: php, mysqli

So, I'm working on a forum script, and am trying to make it that the creator of the thread and the staff members can lock the thread, but "lock" isn't updating.

Here's what's used to trigger the lock (when posting):

`[input type="checkbox" name="lock" value="1" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure? Only staff members can undo this.')" /]` Close this Thread (Disable posting)

Had to change () to [] due to allowance of html

Here's the PHP:

```
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string(db(), $_GET['id']); // This was in the code before. Think I'm stupid?
$eee = "SELECT * FROM forums WHERE id = $id";
    $eeee = query($eee);
    while ($notif = mysqli_fetch_assoc($eeee)) {
        if ($_POST['lock'] = '1') {
            if ($_SESSION['username'] == $notif['creator'] || staffmember()) {
                $hi = "UPDATE forum SET ´lock´ = '1' WHERE ´id´ = '$id'";
                $ooo = query($hi);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just wait until someone sends a lock request with an ID of `' OR '' = '`…  you need to learn about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: $id is mysqli_escape_string(db, $_GET['id']) but it's not in the post because it's only a portion of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My error was here:

```
$hi = "UPDATE forums SET [lock]=1 WHERE id='$id'";
```

I needed to add `` around lock to get it to work, since lock is a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is not taken:

```
$hi = "UPDATE forum SET ´lock´ = '1' WHERE ´id´ = '". $notif['id'] ."'";
```

Please use better variable name for the comprehension.

Comment: No, that didn't do anything.

Also, $id was already defined prior in the code. The variable  name was just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `query` is a custom function which also handles the connection to the db?

Probably this line is your problem `if ($_POST['lock'] = '1') {`

That should be `if ($_POST['lock'] == '1') {`

`=` is an assignment operator `==` is a comparator

And please sort out you sql injection vulnerabilities, your users trust you with their credentials. They shouldn't have to suffer becuase of your security flaws

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't work. Also, I already secured the whole script and made sure of it. Passwords are encrypted anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try `print_r($notif)` because I can't see any other mistake than mistakes already mentioned.

Comment: Messed around, and "lock" still returned 0.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: problem could also be with that input tag... try to comment that if($_POST) and try the script again

@Achrome I know that, unfortunately there is no other way for me, my reputation is too low, so I can't comment other's questions and I want to help...